# How to read an integer and a char with read() function in C?

Tags: c, io

I'm working on linux, I have a file that contains a line like this:

```
328abc
```

I would like, in C, to read the integer part (328) and the characters 'a','b','c', using only the function:

```
ssize_t read (int filedes, void *buffer, size_t size))
```

This is the only thing the file contains.
I know there are better ways to do that with other functions, but I haven't coded in C for a long time, and trying to help a friend, only this function is alowed.
How do I play with the buffer to do that?
Thanks

edit:
I understand that I need to parse the buffer manually. and my question is how?

Comment: C or C++? Those are different languages providing different solutions. I removed the C++ tag for now since your title says C, if you meant C++ instead, edit accordingly.

Comment: Ok, you're right, I edited the question. in C actually.

Comment: The integer part is a fixed number of digits or a pattern of one or more decimal digits?

Comment: it is an integer, a number between 1-1000

Comment: Is that the only thing in the file? Does the file contains several lines of the pattern? Is the pattern shown between other data? Please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, edited.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the function is supposed to do, if this is the whole content of the file. Is the integer part supposed to be returned as the function value, and the alphabetical part in `buffer`?

Comment: actually what I need is really simple, just find the integer part, of the line, and the characters part

Comment: ...and how will the function return those data?

Comment: What do you mean Vane? what function?  im trying to write a program that uses read() func, and get the integer part of the characters in the file.

Comment: First, add terminating 0-byte at the end of the buffer you read (make sure there is room). Then use `strtol` to parse the numeric part at the start of the buffer. `strtol` returns pointer to first char it could not parse, which is rest of the file. If you are not allowed to use `strtol`, then implement it yourself (use different function name though).

Comment: vane, u dont have to unrate the question, you're the only one who doesn't understand it..

Comment: It wasn't me, I  rarely downvote. I never use `read`, I use streams, so I thought what you posted was a function you are supposed to implement (often the case with homework). I'm thick.

Comment: no, ok thanks anyway and sorry for accusation ;)

Comment: @Upsilon42 The question looks like either a "please give me some hints" question, or "please write my code for me" question. I've seen both kinds of questions commonly downvoted at SO.

Comment: Yep, I also dont like "write the code for me" question, but if you try to really read the question, you'll understand that only a piece of code can explain it. besides, I didnt ask for code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's the only thing in the file. This will do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[6];
    char intBuffer[4];
    ssize_t bytesRead;

    int number;
    int fd;

    if ((fd = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((bytesRead = read(fd, buffer, 6)) == -1) {
        perror("Error reading file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memcpy(intBuffer, buffer, 3);
    intBuffer[3] = '\0';

    number = atoi(intBuffer);
    printf("The number is %d\n", number);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The following code will print "The number is 328".

Comment: hey, that's an idea i thought about, and your realisations helps me a lot, BUT, the integer can be any int from 1 to 1000, so it is not a 3 digits number. any other solution?

Comment: Define a bigger buffer 4 digits + 3 letters, check the output of read and you'll know that the integer part will be readBytes - 3. Assuming the letters part has always 3 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Is this some kind of homework?

I am asking because there are better ways to do that than using the `read` function.

Anyway to answer your question, `read` reads `size` bytes from the file whose file descriptor is `filedes` and places them to the `buffer`.

It does not know anything about line breaks etc. So you need to manually find where a line ends, etc. If you want to only use read, then you need to manually parse the buffer after each call to `read` (supposing your files contains many lines, that you want to parse).

Beware that a line may be split between two `read` calls, so you need to handle that case with caution.